# ターミナルの diff で、github のように、行の中で具体的に差分がある部分に色付けをしたい

Tags: unix

github の PR の diff 表示では、行ごとの diff に加えて、行中のどこの部分に差異があるのかを表示してくれます。例えば [linux の PR から適当に拾ってきたこのページ](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/10/files) などが具体例です。

今、コマンドライン上の diff においても、このように色付けができたら便利だろうと思い、その方法を探しています。

---

diff に色を付けようとして、見つかったパッケージは、 [colordiff というツール](https://www.colordiff.org/) で、これを使うと、例えば `+` の行は緑色、`-`の行は赤色といったように、行ごとに色を付与してくれますが、最終的に実現したい github 的な diff の再現において、「行中の差異の部分の表示」はやってくれていないな、と思っています。

#### 質問

github の PR ページの diff のように、行中の差異の部分まで色わけしてくれるような diff を、ターミナル上で実現したいのですが、これが可能になるツールなどはありませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

英語版の [How to colorize diff on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8800578) にいくつか回答が集まっており、
そのうちの一つに [ydiff](https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff) というツールが紹介されています。
(求めているものは "Word-level diff" と英語では表現されるようです)

**表示例:**

[image]

また、Git に [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight) というモジュールが同梱されているのでこれを使う方法もあるようです。

**参考:**
[gitのdiff-highlightを使い始めた](https://udomomo.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/12/01/181404)

Comment: brew install ydiff で導入可能だったこちらを accept いたします。

Answer (score 4):

すでに回答がついていますが、つい一ヶ月ほど前（2021/4/14）に作成されたnpmライブラリで**git-split-diffs**というものも紹介しておきます。自分が使ってみた限りですが、シェル内でGitHubの差分UIをかなり再現しています。

- https://github.com/banga/git-split-diffs

### DEMO1

[Video](https://asciinema.org/a/Bsk7CFtZkDZ4Ea89BwDcbD8LA)

[image: DEMO1]

### DEMO2

[Video](https://asciinema.org/a/7HrYqF2vjfrKXt28bv6BUAcym)

[image: DEMO2]

Answer (score 2):

[delta](https://crates.io/crates/git-delta) などがあります。

紹介してる記事を適当に探してみました
[[Linux便利コマンド] deltaを入れてみる](https://qiita.com/r12tkmt/items/ee504656a8ec0893ef40)

---

deltaは Rust製で, 他にも各種ツールがあるようです
参考までに:
https://github.com/rust-unofficial/awesome-rust#development-tools

Answer (score 0):

```
wdiff foo.txt bar.txt | colordiff
```